# Date comparison in PHP behaving unpredictably

Tags: php, date

I have a date string like this: 2010-9-30 in my $date_string variable.

When I compare strings like this:

```
if ( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( "+20 days", $date_string ) ) )
{
    // it returns true for all dates
}
```

The comparison is true for all dates, even from yesterday, which isn't 20 days ago.  Any idea why that might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: errr I don't see any comparison in your code. you basically say `if ($some_date_string) { do something }`

Answer (score 3):

You are not making any comparisons between dates.  Instead, you are testing whether you can successfully convert the date supplied as the second parameter to `strtotime()` into a valid date.  That result is always true, because every date has a valid date 20 days in the future.

In other words, if `date()` returns a truthy value your condition is TRUE.  It will always return a truthy value unless you pass it an invalid timestamp in its second parameter (for example, the 42nd of February)

If you want to compare the output of that `date()` call to another date string, you will need an additional operand inside your `if()`:

```
if ('2011-09-02' == date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+20 days", $date_string))) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's returning the date in the string format of (for example) `2000-01-01`, which when converted to boolean is `true`.

Instead, check for this:

```
if (time() > strtotime("+20 days", $date_string)) // Returns true if $date_string was in the last 20 days, or is in the future
```

Obviously, if you want dates more than 20 days old only, just flip the `>` to a `<`